# Keras error: var and grad do not have the same shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

The last line of the following code resulted in the error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  var and grad do not have the same shape[64,1] [64,18]
     [[node Adam/Adam/update_12/ResourceApplyAdam (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:774) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_27034]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node Adam/Adam/update_12/ResourceApplyAdam:
 sequential_7/dense_9/MatMul/ReadVariableOp/resource (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py:1222)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I'm not sure where to start with resolving this issue. I don't know where the shape of var and grad are defined

```
#start 
my_model = models.Sequential() 

#first convolutional block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape = (178, 218, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#second block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#third block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#fourth block 
my_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same"))

my_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same")) 

#global average pooling 
my_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

#fully connected layer 
my_model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
my_model.add(BatchNormalization())

#make predictions 
my_model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax")) 

my_model.summary() 

from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint 
es = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", mode="min",verbose=1, patience=5) 

mc = ModelCheckpoint('/content/model.h5', monitor="val_loss", mode="min", verbose=1, save_best_only=True) 

cb_list=[es,mc] 

# compile model 
my_model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]) 

from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

#set up data generator 
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) 

#get batches of training images from the directory 
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/output2/train',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/output2/val',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical') 

history = my_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs = 11, steps_per_epoch=61, validation_data = validation_generator, validation_steps = 667, callbacks = cb_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
my_model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax")
```

change 1 to the number of classes you have, for example if there are 4 classes (labels) rewrite it as:

```
my_model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing the number of units in your last layer with the number of classes you want to predict? One clear error here is that you try to perform multiclass classification but your last layer only contains 1 unit.